# Возможно ли написание слова с чередованием "мак/мок" в данном контексте с "а", а не с "о"?

Tags: чередования

*Пока вы ходили, я успел намакать в глазурь все пирожные.*

Comment: Это не чередование, а два разных глагола.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, такое слово возможно и даже не выглядит устаревшим, хотя источники, его разрешающие, устарели.

Словарь XVIII века:

> НАМАКА́ТЬ, а́ю, а́ет, сов.; Нама́канный (-аный), прич. чего.
> ⊳Изготовить маканием в каком-л. количестве (о свечах).Намакал свѣч
> пуд.

Словарь Даля:

> НАМАКИВАТЬ, намакать свече, наделать, наготовить макая.

Из Нацкорпуса:

> - Намакав лот, измерив глубины и прочее, экспедиция пришла в Кронштадт    осенью 1842 года (А. П. Боголюбов. Записки
>   моряка-художника (1885));
> - Еще хуже пометы слишкомъ большой величины, то есть сильно намаканные    въ масло капсюли... (А. А. Черкасов. Записки охотника
>   Восточной    Сибири (1867)).